# Why this file upload area does not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this file upload box from video tutorial but javascript code does not working. It does not showing the box with the upload file. I can choose the file but it does not show. Can someone help me with this? I am new javascript learner so I do not know how to do it. I will be very grateful if someone can help me with this. Thank you.

```js
window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
    const input = document.getElementById("upload");
    const filewrapper = document.getElementById("filewrapper");
  
    input.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
      let fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
      let filetype = e.target.value.split(".").pop();
      fileshow(fileName, filetype);
    })
  
    const fileshow=(fileName, filetype)=>{
      const showfileboxElem = document.createElement("div");
      showfileboxElem.classList.add("showfilebox");
      const leftElem = document.createElement("div");
      leftElem.classList.add("left");
      const fileTypeElem = document.createElement("span");
      fileTypeElem.classList.add("filetype")
      fileTypeElem.innerHTML = filetype;
      leftElem.append(fileTypeElem);
      const filetitleElem = document.createElement("h3");
      filetitleElem.innerHTML = fileName;
      leftElem.append(filetitleElem);
      showfileboxElem.append(leftElem);
      const rightElem = document.createElement("div");
      rightElem.classList.add("right");
      showfileboxElem.append(rightElem);
      const crossElem = document.createElement("span");
      crossElem.innerHTML = "&#215;";
      rightElem.append(crossElem);
      filewrapper.append(showfileboxElem);
  
      crossElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        filewrapper.removeChild(showfileboxElem);
      })
    }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.box {
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.upload-area-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.uploadlabel {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px dashed aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.uploadlabel span {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: aqua;
}

.uploadlabel p {
  color: aqua;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.uploaded {
  margin: 30px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #222;
}

.showfilebox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-shadow: #00000d 0px 0px 0px 1px, #d1d5db3d 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;
}

.showfilebox .left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.filetype {
  background: aqua;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.left h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: yellowgreen;
  margin: 0;
}

.right span {
  background: aqua;
  color: #fff;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d8714c9903.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.2/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-tWHlutFnuG0C6nQRlpvrEhE4QpkG1nn2MOUMWmUeRePl4e3Aki0VB6W1v3oLjFtd0hVOtRQ9PHpSfN6u6/QXkQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectivizr/1.0.2/selectivizr-min.js" integrity="sha512-0mXreXYrXoy9laHoypsAOjuSCqh57vY+kIdE46k8Hw0yRY1EhJyHWUEAqfHOTrPkBpsbO39/ZPw5HITv8mLVOA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="input-bx">
        <div class="upload-area-title">File</div>
        <form action="">
          <input type="file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.png,.jpeg" hidden id="upload">
          <label for="upload" class="uploadlabel">
            <span><i class="fa-solid fa-upload"></i></span>
            <p>click</p>
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="filewrapper">
        <h3 class="uploaded">Files</h3>
        <div class="showfilebox">
          <div class="left">
            <span class="filetype"></span>
            <h3></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <span>&#215</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="files/test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `class` with `id` at `<div class="filewrapper">` to solve this

```js
window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
    const input = document.getElementById("upload");
    const filewrapper = document.getElementById("filewrapper");
  
    input.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
      let fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
      let filetype = e.target.value.split(".").pop();
      fileshow(fileName, filetype);
    })
  
    const fileshow=(fileName, filetype)=>{
      const showfileboxElem = document.createElement("div");
      showfileboxElem.classList.add("showfilebox");
      const leftElem = document.createElement("div");
      leftElem.classList.add("left");
      const fileTypeElem = document.createElement("span");
      fileTypeElem.classList.add("filetype")
      fileTypeElem.innerHTML = filetype;
      leftElem.append(fileTypeElem);
      const filetitleElem = document.createElement("h3");
      filetitleElem.innerHTML = fileName;
      leftElem.append(filetitleElem);
      showfileboxElem.append(leftElem);
      const rightElem = document.createElement("div");
      rightElem.classList.add("right");
      showfileboxElem.append(rightElem);
      const crossElem = document.createElement("span");
      crossElem.innerHTML = "&#215;";
      rightElem.append(crossElem);
      filewrapper.append(showfileboxElem);
  
      crossElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        filewrapper.removeChild(showfileboxElem);
      })
    }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.box {
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.upload-area-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.uploadlabel {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px dashed aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.uploadlabel span {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: aqua;
}

.uploadlabel p {
  color: aqua;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.uploaded {
  margin: 30px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #222;
}

.showfilebox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-shadow: #00000d 0px 0px 0px 1px, #d1d5db3d 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;
}

.showfilebox .left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.filetype {
  background: aqua;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.left h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: yellowgreen;
  margin: 0;
}

.right span {
  background: aqua;
  color: #fff;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d8714c9903.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.2/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-tWHlutFnuG0C6nQRlpvrEhE4QpkG1nn2MOUMWmUeRePl4e3Aki0VB6W1v3oLjFtd0hVOtRQ9PHpSfN6u6/QXkQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectivizr/1.0.2/selectivizr-min.js" integrity="sha512-0mXreXYrXoy9laHoypsAOjuSCqh57vY+kIdE46k8Hw0yRY1EhJyHWUEAqfHOTrPkBpsbO39/ZPw5HITv8mLVOA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="input-bx">
        <div class="upload-area-title">File</div>
        <form action="">
          <input type="file" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.png,.jpeg" hidden id="upload">
          <label for="upload" class="uploadlabel">
            <span><i class="fa-solid fa-upload"></i></span>
            <p>click</p>
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="filewrapper">
        <h3 class="uploaded">Files</h3>
        <div class="showfilebox">
          <div class="left">
            <span class="filetype"></span>
            <h3></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <span>&#215</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="files/test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```